# How do I make this regular expression skip over a new line in Python?

Tags: python, regex

How would I incorporate a modifier here, like "M"? I read about modifiers to go into "multi-line" mode? I'm wanting to skip a new line anywhere it may be in the search.

```
content= re.sub(r'(title href="#_ftnref\d+"><span lang="en-us">)(.{1,4}<)',r'\1xyz<',content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex should be compiled this way:

```
myregex = re.compile('regex-pattern', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE);
myregex.sub(replacement, target[, count = 0]);
```

More to the point:

```
myregex = re.compile('(title href="#_ftnref\d+"><span lang="en-us">)(.{1,4}<)', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE);
myregex.sub('\1xyz<', content);
```

see [here](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) for more details.

Comment: I don't think you need to quote the second argument.

Comment: How would I incorporate that into my statement above?

Comment: You'd write it this way: `myregex = re.compile(...); myregex.sub(replacement, target[, count]);`. @DSM you're right. My bad.